# Extracting a tag value in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a html document using beautiful soup in python.

I came across a tag like this

```
div class="_3auQ3N">\u20b9<!-- -->1,990</div>
```

\u20bp represents currency symbol and 1,990 is the price.

I want to know how can I extract these values into two different Strings (or values)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_3auQ3N">\u20b9<!-- -->1,990</div>', 'lxml')
>>> list(soup.div.strings)
['₹', '1,990']
```

Comment: I am getting this.. [u'\\u20b9', u'1,990']

Comment: For Python 2, you can: `for s in soup.div.strings: print s.decode('unicode_escape')`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have extracted your string, you may yse regex:

```
import re


string = "\u20b9<!-- -->1,990"
a = re.findall("(^.*)<!-- -->(.*)", string)
print(a[0][0],a[0][1]) # ₹ 1,990
```